# Can't resolve custom type definitions with a turborepo monorepo

Tags: typescript, jestjs, turborepo

I have a turborepo project with the following structure:

```
apps
  - my-app
    - src
      - some-test.spec.ts
    - tsconfig.json
    - types
      - index.d.ts
packages
  - tsconfig
    - base.json
```

The `pacakges/tsconfig/base.json` looks like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "typeRoots": ["../../node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "build"
  ] 
}
```

The `apps/my-app/tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `apps/my-app/types/index.d.ts` had definitions for a library that I'm using and I've overridden them.

The issue I have is that I can't get TypeScript to recognize the jest types.

If I leave just the `types` under the `base.json`'s `compilerOptions`, jest works but the custom-defined type doesn't. If I leave only the `typeRoots`, the custom typings work but not jest's.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. It seems to be a VS Code problem not recognizing the types because the compiler renders my pages correctly.